# Функция выполняется бесконечно Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Функция:

```
def binner(x, col):
  if x == np.nan:
    return 0
  elif x <= np.quantile(binning_df[col].dropna(), 0.25):
    return 1
  elif x <= np.quantile(binning_df[col].dropna(), 0.5) and x > np.quantile(binning_df[col].dropna(), 0.25):
    return 2
  elif x <= np.quantile(binning_df[col].dropna(), 0.75) and x > np.quantile(binning_df[col].dropna(), 0.5):
    return 3
  elif x > np.quantile(binning_df[col].dropna(), 0.75):
    return 4
```

Код:

```
binning_df.ar_revenue.apply(lambda x: binner(x, 'ar_revenue'))
```

Хочу, чтобы данные разбились по бинам, но функция выполняется бесконечно. Функция не заходит в if'ы.

Comment: если функция не пойдёт в ифы, она вернёт нон и завершится. так вечной не получается. проверьте данные

Comment: @Интик я писал принты в каждый if, при выполнении функции ниодного символа не напечаталось, значит функция в иф не заходила

Comment: А я что-то не понял? Так "функция выполняется бесконечно" или "функция не заходит в if'ы"? Если она не заходит в if-ы, то как она может выполняться бесконечно?  Приведите пример (фрагмент) вашего датафрейма.

Comment: Будет быстрее и проще если вы отсортируете колонку `ar_revenue`. Тогда значения  по квантилям попадут в соответствующие части колонки.

Comment: Если сортировка вам не подходит, что вычислите квантили заранее. Получается что вы перевычисляете на каждой итерации, что делает программу очень медленной.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: нашел проще способ. До меня уже была придумана эта функция.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел способ проще и быстрее, чтобы поделить данные на бины:

```
binning_df.ar_revenue = pd.qcut(binning_df.ar_revenue, 5, labels=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Функция разделяет колонку с данными на 5 бинов.

Comment: Вообще-то то, что вы написали не соответствует условию, которое вы привели в своем вопросе.  Это раз. Во-вторых, вопрос был не как разбить данные на заданное (в вопросе-  четыре) интервала, а почему функция то-ли работает бесконечно, то-ли не заходит в if-ы. И на этот вопрос в вашем как-бы ответе ответа-то и нет. А то, что такая функция существует -  это как бы и не новость.

Comment: Надо читать описание вопроса до конца, а в конце написано, что я хочу сделать, а именно разбить данные по бинам. И если человек понял суть вопроса, он бы предложил, как сделать это проще. Внимательнее надо быть)

Comment: Обязательно учту ваш совет, учитывая ваши знания и опыт. А вам советую -  научиться ясно, четко  и однозначно выражать свои мысли. Если захотите когда нибудь вдруг стать программистом - очень пригодиться.